# AttributeError: 'FileField' object has no attribute 'model'

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-models, django-views

I get AttributeError: 'FileField' object has no attribute 'model' whenever i run python manage.py makemigrations and python manage.py migrate
Please see below model.py and my last migration file when i run migrate

Migration: 0014_slider_slider title

```
class Migration(migrations.Migration):

dependencies = [
    ('shops', '0013_auto_20170219_2049'),
]

operations = [
    migrations.AddField(
        model_name='slider',
        name='Slider Title',
        field=models.CharField(default=models.FileField(blank=True, null=True, upload_to=b''), max_length=20),
    ),
]
```

Output of Migrate

```
Operations to perform:
Apply all migrations: admin, auth, contenttypes, sessions, shops
Running migrations:
Applying shops.0014_slider_slider title...Traceback (most recent call last):
File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 367, in execute_from_command_line
utility.execute()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 359, in execute
self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 294, in run_from_argv

self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 345, in execute
output = self.handle(*args, **options)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 204, in handle
fake_initial=fake_initial,
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 115, in migrate
state = self._migrate_all_forwards(state, plan, full_plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 145, in _migrate_all_forwards
state = self.apply_migration(state, migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 244, in apply_migration
state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/migrations/migration.py", line 129, in apply
operation.database_forwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, old_state, project_state)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/migrations/operations/fields.py", line 84, in database_forwards
field,
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/schema.py", line 43, in add_field
super(DatabaseSchemaEditor, self).add_field(model, field)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 395, in add_field
definition, params = self.column_sql(model, field, include_default=True)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 147, in column_sql
default_value = self.effective_default(field)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 221, in effective_default
default = field.get_db_prep_save(default, self.connection)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 755, in get_db_prep_save
prepared=False)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 747, in get_db_prep_value
value = self.get_prep_value(value)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 1081, in get_prep_value
return self.to_python(value)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 1077, in to_python
return smart_text(value)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/encoding.py", line 41, in smart_text
return force_text(s, encoding, strings_only, errors)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/encoding.py", line 78, in force_text
s = six.text_type(s)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 188, in __str__
model = self.model
AttributeError: 'FileField' object has no attribute 'model'
```

models.py

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.db import models


#Create your models here.

class Slider(models.Model):
    slider = models.FileField()
    slider_title = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.slider_title


class ShopCategories(models.Model):
    category = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.category


class NewShop(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(ShopCategories)
    main_image = models.FileField()
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    tagline = models.CharField(max_length=50, default='Enter tagline here2')
    description = models.TextField(default='enter shop description')
    shop_image = models.FileField()
    def __str__(self):
        return  self.name
```

Comment: It looks like your issue will be in a migration file, not your models (please include the migration file that is referenced last when you run migrate)

Comment: @Sayse .. Please have a look now

Comment: Can you please include the stack trace and the output from running migrate?

Comment: @Sayse I have updated with stack trace. Please what do you mean by "the output". Sorry, i'm still relatively new to programming

Comment: That stack trace is related to a different error to the one in your question... When you run migrate, a load of text appears on the screen, (the output)

Comment: @Sayse.. please have a look now

Comment: The migration it is trying to run is `0014_slider_slider title` which I'm guessing isn't the one you're showing here since its unlikely to depend on 0020

Comment: I just added the migration file 0014_slider_slider title to .. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason you've specified another Field type as a default for a charfield which I doubt would ever work, just change this to have a better default for a char field

```
operations = [
    migrations.AddField(
        model_name='slider',
        name='Slider Title',
        field=models.CharField(default='', max_length=20),
    ),
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Because most of the FileField objects you are having are images, Django's ImageField would be a better option than Filefield. Check the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/fields/#imagefield)